# Revisar si un radio button esta checkeado

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de revisar un radio button en javascript si esta checkeado,
el problema surge que en el primer radio button lo toma pero al segundo radio no toma.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" className="radiosbtn" name="sipa" id="sipa" value='false'/>Si
<input type="radio" className="radiosbtn" name="sipa" id="sipa" value='true'/>No
```

Javascript:

```
document
.getElementById("sipa")
.addEventListener("change", event => hasSipaHandlerChanged(event));


export const hasSipaHandlerChanged = event => {
  hasSipa = String(event.target.value);
console.log(event);
  if (hasSipa === "true") {
    const hasSipalDOM = document.querySelector(".has--sipa-gen");

    hasSipalDOM.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `
      <p> lorem, isum</p>
      `
    );
  } else {
    console.log(hasSipa);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que buscas verificar si uno de los 2 `radio` esta seleccionado, considero que es mas simple proceder de este modo:

```
let radios = document.querySelectorAll(".radios")

radios.forEach((elemento) => {
 elemento.addEventListener("change", () => {
   let actividad = (elemento) ? `Cambio, elegiste: ${elemento.value}` : `No cambio`
   console.log(actividad)
 })
})
```

Donde:

- Obtenemos a todos por medio de una clase asignada que en este caso llamaremos `radios`
- Como `querySelectorAll` nos devuelve una lista de nodos de todos los elementos coincidentes entonces los recorremos con un `forEach`
- Ahora por cada `elemento` que obtiene el bucle en sus iteraciones verificamos el `event` de `change` que ocurre cuando seleccionas un `radio`
- Si dicho elemento que representa a uno de los `radios` esta en `checked` entonces su valor es `true` por eso solo lo escribí como: `(elemento)` entonces imprimimos el `value` que posee para no solo saber que fue elegido sino además recuperar que valor tiene asignado dicho `radio button`

**EJEMPLO COMPLETO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="radio" class="radios" className="radiosbtn" name="sipa" id="sipa" value='false'/>Si
    <input type="radio" class="radios" className="radiosbtn" name="sipa" id="sipa" value='true'/>No
    <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>
        let radios = document.querySelectorAll(".radios")
        
        radios.forEach((elemento) => {
         elemento.addEventListener("change", () => {
           let actividad = (elemento) ? `Cambio, elegiste: ${elemento.value}` : `No cambio`
           document.getElementById("aviso").innerHTML = `Elegiste: ${elemento.value}`
         })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```